# How to show that the following function is a bijection?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a bijective function from $\mathbb N_n$ onto a set $A$ -thus, the set $A$ has $n$ elements. Then let $g$ be a function defined on $\mathbb N_{n-1}$ to be $f(i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,k-1$ and $f(i+1)$ for $i=k,\ldots,n-1$ for some $k \in \mathbb N_n$, i.e., $g$ maps onto every element of $A$ except for the element $f(k)$. How to show that $g$ is a bijection?

EDIT: yes, I meant $k \in \mathbb N_n$

Comment: I assume you mean that $k\in\Bbb N_n.$ Also, note that in order to prove that $g$ is a bijection, a codomain must be specified.

Comment: The codomain would be the set $A$ except for the element $f(k)$,i.e. let $C$ be a subset of $A$ such that $C = \{f(k)\}$, then the codomain would be $A\setminus C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**: It seems that what you mean to show is that $g$ is a bijection $\Bbb N_{n-1}\to A\setminus\{f(k)\},$ where $$g(i)=\begin{cases}f(i) & \text{for }1\le i<k\\f(i+1) & \text{for }k\le i<n.\end{cases}$$ It's clear that $g$ is a function on $\Bbb N_{n-1},$ and since $f:\Bbb N_n\to A,$ then $g:\Bbb N_{n-1}\to A.$ By injectivity of $f,$ we can show that $g$ is injective and that $A\setminus\{f(k)\}$ is a codomain of $g.$ By surjectivity of $f,$ we can show that $g$ maps $\Bbb N_{n-1}$ onto $A\setminus\{f(k)\}.$

Comment: I do not see how to show that $g$ is injective by the injectivity of $f$

Comment: Suppose $g(i)=g(j)$ for some $i,j\in\Bbb N_{n-1}$. Without loss of generality, suppose that $i\le j$. Thus, there are three possible cases to consider: (1) $i<k\le j$, (2) $i,j<k,$ and (3) $k\le i,j$. One of them is impossible (due to injectivity and the definition of $g$). Both of the other two cases lead to the conclusion $i=j$ by using the injectivity of $f$ and the definition of $g.$

Comment: Why would the case where $i \lt k \le j$ be impossible?

Comment: Apologies for the misleading phrasing. I mean that since $i\le j,$ then it follows that one of the three cases must hold. The $i<k\le j$ case is, in fact, the impossible case.

Comment: Oops! I misread your earlier comment. If $i<k\le j,$ then $$f(i)=g(i)=g(j)=f(j+1),$$ so since $f$ is injective, then $i=j+1,$ which is impossible, since then $i<j<j+1=i.$