# How to show that the union of an infinite set and a finite set is infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $C$ be an infinite set and let $B$ be a finite set. Then, how can one show that $C \cup B$ is an infinite set?

Comment: Pseudo-hint: how did you define an infinite set?

Comment: As a set that is not finite,i.e., a set for which no bijection from $\mathbb N_n$ onto the set itself exists.

Comment: Check their cardinalities?

Comment: Any subset of a finite set is finite itself. Go for contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps you can show this: a set is finite iff there exists an injection from it to $\Bbb N_n$, for some $n$.

Comment: Hint: If $C\cap B=\emptyset$, then obviously, $C\cup B$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose by way of contradiction that there is some $n$ for which a bijection exists $\Bbb N_n\to C\cup B.$ You can then use the result from [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668080/how-to-show-that-the-following-function-is-a-bijection/668095?noredirect=1#comment1404436_668095) to show that it follows (by removing the elements of $B$ that aren't already in $C$ one at a time) that there is a bijection $\Bbb N_m\to C$ for some $m\le n.$ This is impossible, though, since $C$ is infinite.